# compare fields values for a controller, no trigger, Schema.DescribeSObjectResult?

Tags: custom-field, schema

I'm trying to find out how to compare fields values for changes. I have for custom fields that I need to know if they have changed before the user clicks on Save to run a logic before saving. This is for an custom controller. The idea is to use this for logic like these:

1. If 4 customField__c are blank and were previously blank, hasError = true.
2. If 1 customField__c was not previously blank and change, hasError = false.
   etc ...

I have been reading a bit about **Dynamic Apex** and specially the **Schema.DescribeSObjectResult** that it looks like the way to go. I was hopping that someone could put here a simple example to help me understand this. 
Thanks in advanced.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Code for save button. It will be action method for the save button.
public pagereference customSave(){
    Boolean hasError = false;

    //Below code Gives the old record values as the new values are not been saved yet
    CustomObject__c obj = [select customField1__c,customField2__c from CustomObject__c where id =:yourRecord.id];
    if((obj.customField1__c==null || obj.customField1__c=='') && (yourRecord.customField1__c==null || yourRecord.customField1__c==''))
         hasError = true;
    if(hasError){
         ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Your Error Message');
         ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
    }
    else
         upsert yourRecord;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Value changes of records can be easily managed in triggers since they have the context to compare what we need. I don't know about a way to do such a comparison with `DescribeSObjectResult`. As far as I know `describeSObjects()` returns `DescribeSObjectResult` typeof array which gives us the **meta data** information, not anything about specific records(values).
If you really need to check the field changes in a controller you can use something like @snehakem's logic.

```
public class ctrl{
    //Record binds with the UI
    MyObject__c editRecord = [select Id, customField1__c,customField2__c from MyObject__c where id =:yourRecord.id];

    public void saveRecord(){
        Boolean hasError = false;

        //Original record
        MyObject__c originalRecord = [select customField1__c,customField2__c from MyObject__c where id =:yourRecord.id];

        //Compare fields of original record against the record which you bind with the UI
        //I'm sorry I'm not that much clear your business logic, so add those as you need
        if(editRecord.customField1__c=='' && editRecord.customField2__c=='' && editRecord.customField3__c=='' && editRecord.customField4__c==''){
            if(originalRecord.customField1__c=='' && originalRecord.customField2__c=='' && originalRecord.customField3__c=='' && originalRecord.customField4__c==''){
                hasError = true;
                // your stuffs
                // Please add conditions as per your business since I'm not clear those
            }
        }
        if(!hasError){
            upsert editRecord; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: snehakem, highfive thank you guys. Both answers helped, but I have to say that the snehakem's approach was the best option for my intentions.